# It seems like yesterday

Tags: sentence-choice

I am going to make up an example:

> Time goes very quickly. It has been twenty years since I last met Jack. **It seems like yesterday.**

Does the clause in bold make sense? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes it does. You definitely say that. Some also use 'just' or 'only' before 'yesterday'. 'It seems like just yesterday'.

Comment: I wouldn't have written it as three sentences, but that's probably just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the sentence presented; it's grammatical.

According to Merriam Webster, the idiom "it seems like only yesterday" is used to say that something seems like it just happened.

It's been over a year since we met, but it seems like only yesterday.